# How to create an Oracle number with at least 11 digits?

Tags: database, oracle, floating-point, numbers

I need to create a datatype, which supports numbers with at least x digits and be able to store also more than x digits.

In TCPE the datatype is called NUM(m[,n]). M means an unsigned numeric value with at least m total digits, of which n Digits are to the right after the decimal point.

So NUM(11) how would I create a datatype for this in oracle?

I was thinking about NUMBER(11,0) but seems this is the maximum amount of bits.
Maybe floating point is able to solve this problem?

Or should I use a check constraint? But using a check constraint seemed a little bit strange as I thought this would be natively supported.

Comment: What's the point of having "at least x digits"? Is the problem in storing a value or in representing the value to a user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to declare the numeric type that contains "at least x digits and be able to store also more than x digits".

All you can do is just declare it as `NUMBER(38,0)` (the largest possible integer) and create constraint to check if the number is less than X digits length.

**UPD**

Also as you mentioned yourself `NUMBER(*, 0)` is also a valid way to do the same work.

Comment: Shouldn't I use NUMBER(*, 0) is it the same?

Comment: @Sam S: is `*` a valid value for precision?!

Comment: @zerkms: Yes. [You can specify a scale and no precision](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209)

Comment: In Oracle number(38,0) is the largest possible precision.

Comment: @Janek Bogucki: yep, my bad... 2 discoveries per one answer, great result ;-) Thanks